# Converting input from a file to a Date in java

Tags: java, date, type-conversion, string-conversion, java.util.date

I have a text file I am importing data from that is information about items in a library. One of these pieces of information is the date the item was loaned. I cannot figure out what syntax I need to get the text from the file that will be in dd/MM/yyyy format read in and converted to a Date value using

```
import java.util.Date;
```

As it currently sits, the error is "cannot find symbol

symbol: method SimpleDateFormat(String)
location: class digitalLibrary

I am not wanting it to look for a method I wrote... Instead I believe what I want it to do is use

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public static Item createLibrary (ArrayList <Item> library)
{
    Scanner reader = null;
    try {
        File inputFile = new File("library.txt");
        reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not open the file.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //This loop fills the ArrayList with the input from the library.txt file
    for (int i =0; reader.hasNext(); i++)
    {
        Item a = new Item();
        a.setTitle(reader.nextLine());
        a.setFormat(reader.nextLine());
        a.setOnLoan(Boolean.parseBoolean(reader.nextLine()));
        a.setLoanedTo(reader.nextLine());
        //My problem is in the next two lines of code, specifically
        //SimpleDateFormat
        String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        a.setDateLoaned(SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(reader.nextLine()));
        reader.nextLine();

        //This adds the item with all the attributes to the ArrayList library
        library.add(a);
    }   
}
```

This is separate code I have written inside my Item class for when I ask the user for when the item was loaned out that is similar and works:

```
public Date getTheDateLoaned()
{
    System.out.println("What day was it loaned out in dd/MM/yyyy format?");
    String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try 
    {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(scanner.nextLine());
    } 
    catch (ParseException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("This was not in the right format. The format"
                + "needs to be dd/MM//yyyy");
    }
return null;
}
```

Thank you again for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the entire exact printout of the error, I can't be sure, but it looks like you haven't imported SimpleDateFormat.
Before your class statement, add the line `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`, and you should be all set. Did you try this?

Also, you forgot `new`.
Try this:

```
a.setDateLoaned((new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat)).parse(reader.nextLine()));
```

Comment: I did actually use the import. Sorry, I stated the import before the code, but didn't explicitly state that I imported it. I believe all I needed was "new" like you said! That is embarrasing, lol.

Comment: Ok, how about my example that includes the `new` keyword?

Comment: Yes, I needed the "new" keyword in a.setDateLoaned(SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(reader.nextLine()));

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Not sure about your error. You **definitely need to have an `import` statement** in place appropriate to the classes you want to invoke in your code.

More importantly:

- You are inappropriately trying to represent a date-only value in a date-time object.
- You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Use the java.time classes while avoiding the legacy classes whenever possible. No need for `Date` nor `SimpleDateFormat`.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Big tip: When serializing date-time values as text, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The standard formats are sensible, practical, easy to read by humans across cultures, and easy to parse by machine. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. Present date-time values in localized formats to suit the user, but **store and exchange data in standard formats**.

For a date-only value, the standard format is YYYY-MM-DD such as `2017-01-23`.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
```

Parse your input string.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "23/01/2017" , f );
```

Trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) in case of bad inputs.

## Time zone

If this app were for a small local library, you could use `LocalDate` as the due-date. But if contractually the exact moment when due is critical, or your app may be used across time zones, you should use a date-time value instead of a date-only value.

In such a case search Stack Overflow for many discussions and examples of the java.time classes `Instant`, `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, and `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response! This is my first time dealing with date and time in programming, and I appreciate you guiding me in the best practices.